# Problema al crear un job en SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

Consulta espero que me puedan ayudar.

Le comento que cree un JOB en SQL SERVER 2012 pero dentro de ese JOB he creado 3 pasos como la imagen: lo que pasa esque cuando quiero guardar me sale ese error:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Solucion: en cada paso del jobs se debe cambiar la succesion a : GO TO THE NEXT STEP que significa seguir al siguiente paso del job .

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]